# php/mysql can't run same file twice at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, centos, server

I'm trying to make a "robot" do some data processing but can't figure out how to run the same file twice and speed up the processing with multiple processes of same file.

My code:

```
while($stop != 1){

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `state` = 'nothing' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if(empty($row)){
        echo $i." stop";
        $stop = 1;
    }else{
        echo "do ".$i."<br/>";
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `data` SET `state` = 'done' WHERE `id` = '{$row['id']}'");
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Pretty simple, right?

The file continues until there is no more `state` = 'nothing' in the database and it works fine with one file...

It just goes like:

```
do 1
do 2
do 3
do 4
do 5
do 6
do 7
```

(There are like 3000 rows in the database)

But if I run the same file second time it doesn't do anything and just waits for the other file to finish and then just writes "1 stop" meaning it did nothing even if I started the files at the same time.

I noticed if I start the both files at the same and cancel the execution of the first file - the second file just starts from 1 id even through like 500 of lines are already `state` = 'nothing'.

It got me thing now... is this a php or mysql problem? How can I make one file runned twice process different data and not hang up like this?

CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2014 12:19:25)

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.5.38                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your mysql table is locked during update

Comment: You need to read up on [table and row locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html), particularly if your table is using the MyISAM engine.

Comment: as a complement of the 2 comments before, both programs can do the select at the same time (I don't think reading lock the ressource), so they will both have all rows. Then, if you stop one, the 2nd won't update its knowledge about the select he did. So he will still go through all rows... To avoid this, you could also check your data state before updating, to see if it has already been catched by an other program after the SELECT...

Comment: I'm using MyISAM, would switching to InnoDB help?I can't really avoid updating the table because the script needs to see which data was already processed. @Random is this what you're talking about? Updated the first post with a code

Comment: I was just talking about the if condition, you don't have to update `$result` and `$row` inside the `else`, it would be dramatic for performances.

Comment: You're right, I understood it now :) but I still don't understand how to avoid that table locking

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it because I still can't find a way to get pass it

Comment: the fact is that you can't... when you write in a table, no one else can write in the table. It is the same thing for file writing. If 2 threads write "Hello World" in a file, it may result as "HelHellloo  WoWrldorld", and this is not acceptable... ! So if you want 2 threads to write at the same time, it has to be on different tables. So a solution may be to cut your table in different parts. If it is a phone book, you could make a table for each letter, and so use 26 threads to update. (but it won't be 26 times faster !)

Answer (score 0):

try to use different query
ex:

> localhost/a.php?process=1
>
> localhost/a.php?process=2

this will make your file run twice in the same time